# MySQL - Compare values of two tables and log them

Tags: mysql

I have three MySQL Tables

- My `import` table gets product values from a cronjob
- My `products` table stores all products
- My `log` table should store all changes (add, remove, change)

I want to compare my `import` table with my `product` table (they both have the same scheme) and then get if there were products added, removed or changed. Plus I need to know *which* product got changed/added/removed (e.g by the product number - not PK) and log that into my `log` table.

Comment: Export the content of the tables in CSV files, use a (preferably GUI) diff tool to find the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can select rows of products that are in one table and not in the other as follows:

`SELECT * FROM import WHERE product_number NOT IN (SELECT product_number FROM products);`

Assuming these are the products that must be added, first write to `log`:

`INSERT INTO log ( product_number, description ) SELECT product_number, 'Added' FROM import WHERE product_number NOT IN (SELECT product_number FROM products);`

Then update `products`:

`INSERT INTO products SELECT * FROM import WHERE product_number NOT IN (SELECT product_number FROM products);`

For products that must be deleted, select rows in `products` that are not in `import`, and for products that must be changed, select rows in `import` and `products` that have the same `product_number` but differ in other fields.